# For Loop blocking other For Loop

Tags: python, loops, pygame, collision-detection

I'm checking missileGroup to see if any instances of missile collided with any instances enemy in enemyGroup. When run, it prints "Hit" for the first loop, but it ignores the second for loop. Why is that?

```
 #### Imagine this is in a game loop ####
    for missile in missileGroup:
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(missile, enemyGroup, False) :
            print("Hit")

    
    for enemy in enemyGroup:
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(enemy, missileGroup, False):
            print("HI")
```

**Update**: @Rabbid76 stated that `spritecollide` wouldn't work because the spriteGroup `enemyGroup` is a  list of sprites within a group(enemyGroup <- enemyList <- Enemy(sprite)) instead of a group of sprites(enemyGroup <- Enemy(sprite)). How would I access that?

**Update 2** @paxdiablo stated that the first loop maybe emptying the group after iterating. I switched the places of the loops and 2nd loop ran, while the 1st did not.

**Update 3** In the full code, `.reset()` method runs `.kill()` which removes the sprite from the group. Since the first loop removes the missile sprite before the second loop couldn't detect any collisions:

```
for missile in missileGroup:
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(missile, enemyGroup, False) :
        missile.reset()

for eachEnemy in enemyGroup: 
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(eachEnemy, missileGroup, False):
            eachEnemy.reset()
```

Comment: There's nothing in the first loop that would prevent the second loop from running.  Either `enemyGroup` is empty, or the spritecollide function always returns false.

Comment: Is there code in between the two loops your have removed for the question?  If a missile collides with something in `enemyGroup`, there must be an enemy to collide with the `missileGroup`.

Comment: What version of PyGame are you using?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, `missileGroup` is a bunch of sprites while `enemyGroup` is a bunch of sprites in a list(Not sure if that matters)

Comment: @Kingsley 3.8.5

Comment: @Rabbid76 Unfortunately no. I switched the places of the loops and 2nd loop ran, while the 1st did not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225293/discussion-between-daeshaun-morrison-and-rabbid76).

Comment: @Rabbid76 `enemyGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()`, it is no longer a list of sprites within a group(enemyGroup <- enemyList <- Enemy(sprite)) instead of a group of sprites(enemyGroup <- Enemy(sprite)). I tried your answer(check out update in the post)

Comment: @DaeshaunMorrison `missile.reset()` respectively `eachEnemy.reset()` causes the 2nd loop to fail. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide):

> Return a list containing all Sprites in a Group that intersect with another Sprite.

Therefore the arguments to `spritecollide()` must be a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object and a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) object.
A list of `pygame.sprite.Sprite` objects instead of the *Group* does not work.

```py
missileGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemyGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

```
for missile in missileGroup:
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(missile, enemyGroup, False):
        print("Hit")

for enemy in enemyGroup:
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(enemy, missileGroup, False):
        print("HI")
```

---

Furthermore read about [`kill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill)

> The Sprite is removed from **all** the Groups that contain it.

Hence if you call `kill()` in the 1st loop, the 2nd loop won't work, because the sprite is removed from **all** Groups.

You call `kill()` in the `reset` methods. `missile.reset()` respectively `eachEnemy.reset()` causes the 2nd loop to fail.

Comment: I have that. However, when the first loop, runs the other does not. pastebin: https://pastebin.com/XnF0X2PW

Answer (score 0):

There's no obvious reason, based on the information provided<sup>(a)</sup>, why the second collision check should fail. If there's a collision between (for example) enemy #7 and missile #3, there should *also* be a collision between missile #3 and enemy #7.

You're not using any edge-case stuff like providing your own (possibly non-commutative) collision function, so it will simply use the sprite rectangle to detect this.

I'd be curious to see the behaviour when you *reverse* the order of the two loops in the code.

---

Also, you should specify the types of those group variables. If `enemyGroup` were something like an exhaustible generator rather than a list, it would be "emptied" by the first loop and then the second loop would have no items to iterate over<sup>(b)</sup> (the `spritecollide` call will be iterating over the group to check each item against the sprite).

That's about the only way, short of a bug in `spritecollide` itself, that you would see the effects you're describing.

---

By way of example, here's a piece of code that tries to iterate over a generator twice:

```py
class gen3(object):
    def __init__(self): self._num = 0
    def __iter__(self): return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self._num == 3: raise StopIteration()
        self._num += 1
        return self._num - 1

gen = gen3()
print("A: ")
for i in gen: print(" ", i)
print("B: ")
for i in gen: print(" ", i)
```

The output shows that the second loop does nothing:

```
A:
  0
  1
  2
B:
```

---

Lastly, a definitive way to check the state of the groups is to simply put the following code before each loop:

```py
print("loop X enemy  ", len(enemyGroup),   enemyGroup)
print("loop X missile", len(missileGroup), missileGroup)
```

using a suitable value of `X` to distinguish between the two loops.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Of course, there's always the *possibility* the information you've given is not fully accurate or complete (no malicious intent is supposed but sometimes people inadvertently skip what they *consider* to be unimportant details, that ends up being *very* important).

Example: there may be something happening *between* those two loops which is causing the issue. I'd prefer to give people the benefit of the doubt but you should probably let us know if that's the case.

---

<sup>(b)</sup> It would actually be emptied by the first *iteration* of the first loop so you'd find that it would probably only ever match for the first missile.

Comment: When the first loop is commented out or if the loops are switched, then the second loop(enemyGroup) would run. As you said, earlier it It could be emptied by the first iteration of the first loop, how would I know?

Comment: Is there a way run a for loop to check all items in two lists or groups? I would like to run a method called `.reset` on both `missile` and `enemy` but only on the ones that collided and not all the items.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example that shows (in PyGame 1.9.6) this reported  behaviour does not happen.

The example creates two [sprite groups](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), then collides them in the *exact* same way as the OP's example code.

As well as printing, the sprites change from outline -> filled, depending on whether they believe they have participated in a collision.  There's a 1:1 mapping of an Enemy colliding with a Missile, and vice-versa.

Apologies for the poor frame-rate...
[image: collision_demo]

```
import pygame
import random

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 800

DARK_BLUE = (   3,   5,  54 )
RED       = ( 200,   0,   0 )
YELLOW    = ( 240, 250,   0 )
BLACK     = (   0,   0,   0 )
GREY      = ( 200, 200, 200 )
GREEN     = ( 250,   0,   0 )
TRANSPARENT=( 0,0,0,0 )


class Shape(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width=48, height=48):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface( ( width, height ), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        # Start position is randomly across the screen, and a little off the top
        self.rect.center = ( random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH ), random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )
        # Movement
        self.dx = random.randrange( -2, 2 )
        self.dy = random.randrange( -2, 2 )
        # Looks like
        self.filled = 2
        self.last_fill = -1
        self.render()

    def setFilled( self, value ):
        if ( value == True ):
            self.filled = 0
        else:
            self.filled = 2

    def update( self ):
        if ( self.last_fill != self.filled ):
            self.last_fill = self.filled
            self.render()

        self.rect.move_ip( self.dx, self.dy )

        if ( self.rect.left > WINDOW_WIDTH ):
            self.rect.x = -self.rect.width
        elif ( self.rect.right < 0 ):
            self.rect.left = WINDOW_WIDTH
        if ( self.rect.y > WINDOW_HEIGHT ):
            self.rect.y = 0
        elif ( self.rect.y < 0 ):
            self.rect.y = WINDOW_HEIGHT


class Square( Shape ):
    def render( self ):
        # Something to draw

        if ( self.filled == 0 ):
            self.image.fill( RED )
        else:
            border=3
            x, y = border, border
            width = self.rect.width - border -1
            height = self.rect.height - border -1
            self.image.fill( TRANSPARENT )
            pygame.draw.rect( self.image, RED, (x,y,width,height), self.filled )

class Circle( Shape ):
    def render( self ):
        self.image.fill( TRANSPARENT )
        pygame.draw.circle( self.image, YELLOW, (self.rect.width//2, self.rect.height//2), self.rect.width//2, self.filled )




### initialisation
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )

### Some sprite groups
missileGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range( 3 ):
    new_missile = Circle()
    new_missile.render()
    missileGroup.add( Circle() )

enemyGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range( 12 ):
    new_enemy = Square()
    new_enemy.render()
    enemyGroup.add( Square() )


### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
            # On mouse-click
            pass
    # Move * collide the sprites
    missileGroup.update()
    enemyGroup.update()

    # Test Collisions
    for missile in missileGroup:
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(missile, enemyGroup, False) :
            print("Missile " + str(missile) + " Hits Enemy")
            missile.setFilled( True )
        else:
            missile.setFilled( False )

    for enemy in enemyGroup:
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(enemy, missileGroup, False):
            print("Enemy  " + str(enemy) + " Hits Missile")
            enemy.setFilled( True )
        else:
            enemy.setFilled( False )


    # Paint the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.fill( DARK_BLUE )
    enemyGroup.draw( window )
    missileGroup.draw( window )
    pygame.display.flip()


    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick(60)


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: @paxdiablo Mentioned that it could have been emptied by the first iteration of the first loop, how would I know?

Comment: @DaeshaunMorrison - It would only be emptied if you used the "kill" argument to remove collided items from the group.  Your code specified this as False, so that's not happening here.

Comment: Turn out I was. `.reset()` runs `kill()`